# LINQ Order By Query for XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

Hi I have the following problem:

I am trying to do the following on an XML file: sort all STRUCTs according to the ID attribute of STRING. But return a list of CONTENT objects. The XML can contain  more than one  element.

```
<OBJECT>
  <CONTENT>
     <STRUCT>
        <STRING ID="2">string</STRING>
     </STRUCT>
     <STRUCT>
        <STRING ID="1">string1</STRING>
     </STRUCT>
   </CONTENT>
</OBJECT>
<OBJECT>
  <CONTENT>
     <STRUCT>
        <STRING ID="345">string</STRING>
     </STRUCT>
     <STRUCT>
        <STRING ID="333">string</STRING>
     </STRUCT>
   </CONTENT>
</OBJECT>
```

I am using the following LINQ query, but the strings are not being sorted:

```
Dim Contents = From nm In origXML.Descendants("CONTENT")
    Let ID = nm.Element("STRUCT").Element("STRING").Attribute("ID")
    Order By ID Ascending
    Select nm

For Each xmlString In Contents....
```

Desired output

```
<OBJECT>
  <CONTENT>
     <STRUCT>
        <STRING ID="1">string</STRING>
     </STRUCT>
     <STRUCT>
        <STRING ID="2">string1</STRING>
     </STRUCT>
   </CONTENT>
</OBJECT>
<OBJECT>
  <CONTENT>
     <STRUCT>
        <STRING ID="333">string</STRING>
     </STRUCT>
     <STRUCT>
        <STRING ID="345">string</STRING>
     </STRUCT>
   </CONTENT>
</OBJECT>
```

I know there must be other ways to do this, but I want to know if it's possible using LINQ?

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a single linq query can give you the desired output. In order to properly create a new xml document, which has the same structure as the original one, you need multiple nested linq queries applied to the original xml document.

Assuming that the root node of your XML is `<OBJECTS>`, the following piece of code should give you the desired output:

```
Dim xElement As XElement = New XElement("OBJECTS",
                              From obj In origXML.Descendants("OBJECT")
                              Select New XElement("OBJECT",
                                 From content In obj.Descendants("CONTENT")
                                 Select New XElement("CONTENT",
                                    From st In content.Descendants("STRUCT")
                                    Let ID = Convert.ToInt32(st.Element("STRING")
                                                    .Attribute("ID").Value)
                                    Order By ID Ascending
                                    Select New XElement("STRUCT",
                                       New XElement("STRING", st.Element("STRING").Value, 
                                          New XAttribute("ID", ID)))
                                    )
                                )
                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `<OBJECT><CONTENT>` hierarchy is static (no attributes, etc., that need to be copied to the output), then you could do this in one LINQ query, using VB.NET's nifty support for [XML literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx) with embedded queries.

```vb
Dim origXML =
<OBJECTS>
    <OBJECT>
        <CONTENT>
            <STRUCT>
                <STRING ID="2">string2</STRING>
            </STRUCT>
            <STRUCT>
                <STRING ID="1">string1</STRING>
            </STRUCT>
        </CONTENT>
    </OBJECT>
    <OBJECT>
        <CONTENT>
            <STRUCT>
                <STRING ID="345">string345</STRING>
            </STRUCT>
            <STRUCT>
                <STRING ID="333">string333</STRING>
            </STRUCT>
        </CONTENT>
    </OBJECT>
</OBJECTS>
Dim out = New XDocument(New XElement("OBJECTS",
    From c In origXML...<CONTENT>
    Select _
    <OBJECT>
        <CONTENT>
            <%= From s In c.<STRUCT> Order By CInt(s.<STRING>.@ID) Select s %>
        </CONTENT>
    </OBJECT>
))
```

The `out` variable will be an XDocument with the following content:

```
<OBJECTS>
    <OBJECT>
        <CONTENT>
            <STRUCT>
                <STRING ID="1">string1</STRING>
            </STRUCT>
            <STRUCT>
                <STRING ID="2">string2</STRING>
            </STRUCT>
        </CONTENT>
    </OBJECT>
    <OBJECT>
        <CONTENT>
            <STRUCT>
                <STRING ID="333">string333</STRING>
            </STRUCT>
            <STRUCT>
                <STRING ID="345">string345</STRING>
            </STRUCT>
        </CONTENT>
    </OBJECT>
</OBJECTS>
```

As noted, this is recreating the `<OBJECT>` and `<CONTENT>` elements, so any attributes on those elements would be lost.